# method copy of object '_Worksheet' failed issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie to VBA and am trying to merge sheets from several workbooks into one for further processing.  I keep getting the title error message on worksheets that are named in this convention "1_01_2023".  The same code works perfectly for worksheets named with letters, but breaks once the numbers get involved.  Can you please help me out? Here is the code I've been using

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook
    
    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then
        
        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0
            
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            
            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook
            
            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1
                
                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)
                
                For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                    wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)      ***It breaks right here***
                Next
                
                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                
            Next
            
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            
            MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If
        
    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to have `countSheets = 0` inside the first loop?

Comment: Check e.g. for an additional space in the name

Comment: `Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer` in this line, only `countSheets` is an integer - the type must be specified for _each_ variable when you declare multiple variables on a single line.

Comment: Try referencing the `Worksheets` collection, rather than the `Sheets` collection, since they are not the same (the latter also includes chart sheets).